# Need a simple Phone Gap based Popover example which works on three platform Windows , Android , IOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, twitter-bootstrap, windows-phone-8

I m building a hybrid application for multiple platform such windows , android and IOS.

Following is the snippet for Popover which is working in android and IOS phone

```
 <button id="alarmbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" data-contentwrapper=".myAnalyticscontent" rel="Analyticspopover" style="width: 32%;"><img src="resources/images/alarms.png" /></button>
```

and script code for this popover

```
<div class="myAnalyticscontent" id="myAnalyticscontent"> <!-- Here i    define     my content and add an attribute data-contentwrapper t0 a selector-->
   <h3 id="alarmlabel" >Set Alarm Type</h3>
  <hr id="alarmform"></hr>
<script>
$('[rel=Analyticspopover]').popover({
    html: true,
    placement: 'top',
    content: function () {
        return $($(this).data('contentwrapper')).html();
    }
});
</script>         
</div>
```

The Above piece of code is functional in Android Phone, but in windows phone this code was crashing because of inner HTML exception. So I added

```
<script src="thirdparty/winstore-jscompat.js"></script>
```

because of this No exception is seen,but Popover also is not functional in windows phone.

I have tried the following link, this doesn't work on Windows

http://jsfiddle.net/szkrx/

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: innerHtml Exception was seen only on Windows. but after adding winstore-jscompat.js. no exception was seen . But No pop also